# Azure Kubernetes (AKS) does not release public IPs

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

We are using managed Kubernetes in Azure (AKS) and have run out of public IP addresses. We only need one, but AKS creates a new public IP every time we deploy a service and it does not delete it when the service is deleted. For example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: somename
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 443
  selector:
    app: somename
  # Also tried this to reuse public IP in AKS MC resource group
  # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-my/azure/aks/static-ip
  # loadBalancerIP: x.x.x.x
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Every time this is deployed (`kubectl create -f svc.yml`) a new public IP is created. When it is deleted (`kubectl delete -f svc.yml`) the IP remains. Trying to reuse one of the existing IPs with loadBalanceIP as in the comments above fails, "Public ip address ... is referenced by multiple ipconfigs in resource ...".

We have created a service request but it takes ages, so I'm hoping this will be faster. I don't dare to just delete the public IPs in the AKS managed resource as that may cause issues down the line.

Is there a way to safely release or reuse the public IPs? We are using Kubernetes version 1.7.12. We have deleted the deployment referenced by the service as well, it makes no difference.

Comment: Hi, you should use **apply** instead of **create** when you are deploying an application in the cluster.  Now if you update already existed application public IP will not change.

Comment: Thanks! That will reduce churn, but it will still not release old addresses, so it is only a stop-gap solution. If a new address is created every time a load balancer is created and not reclaimed when it is destroyed they will run out eventually.

Comment: yea. I am using AKS as well. However, I did not encounter this error. It's supposed to be deleted from the external loadbalancer when the service is deleted.

Comment: Do you use Kubernetes 1.7.x or one of the newer versions?

Comment: I am having k8s 1.8.1

Comment: I would suggest you to create an issue on the [Azure/AKS](https://github.com/Azure/AKS). Azure Team might give you reasonable answer.

Comment: We are running out of time, so we will probably need to recreate the cluster in order to fix this now. I'll use a newer k8s version, perhaps that does it. If the error remains I will create an issue on Github as a complement to the existing SR in Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should delete the IPs after some time (like 5 minutes tops). So the issue you are having is a bug. You can check k8s events to find the error and look at it.

Also, its perfectly safe to delete Azure resources. k8s wont freak out if they are gone.

Tested with k8s 1.9.1

Comment: How do you check k8s events? Do you mean kubectl describe or something else? As for the other point we have had serious issues with AKS after a seemingly safe modification originally suggested by support and were told in clear terms not to touch anything in the MC resource group, so I don't want to do something that seems to work now and that breaks a future upgrade later.

Comment: by using `kubectl get events` you get the list of events in the cluster.

Comment: Thanks. It reports the same error as kubectl describe plus warnings about cgroup memory.limit_in_bytes, but nothing interesting.

Comment: well, I use events to understand which actions are serialised and which action happen parallel.  Some events depend on other events. It helps to create a sense out of it.

Comment: It was a bug. Recreating the cluster helped. Note that it was not possible to delete the IP addresses manually either, Azure thought they were in use.